# Compilation error about "expected specifier-qualifier-list before"

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I just start my networking assignment about networking but immediately have an annoying error

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>  
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct client_table{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    memset(&server_addr,0,sizeof(server_addr));
    struct client_table *next;
    int client_no;
} client_table;
```

The error message is

```
mserver.c:13:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘server_addr’
```

I have googled it but nothing helps. Please help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not put code into a type/struct definition. What are those two lines supposed to define? `server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET; memset(&server_addr,0,sizeof(server_addr));`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further on `Marion`'s comment...

"struct" is a variable declaration (similar to "int i;"), and can NOT contain code, such as the assignment of AF_INET of server_add.sin_family and the memset call.  These action MUST be performed elsewhere, perhaps in your main()?  Although it IS possible to pre-initialize a struct, it must be done in a manner similar to initializing any other variable (i.e., "int i = 0;"), but you must specify values for ALL structure fields, separated by commas, enclosed with curly-braces.  If you have nested structures (as is the case with server_addr), the initialization data for THAT element will have to be ANOTHER structure initializer, with ALL fields specified, and again enclosed in curly-braces.  Personally, I'd just move the two lines of executable code to main() and be done with it.

Here is a more simplified example of nested structure initialization:

```
struct coord {
    int x, y;
};
struct box {
    struct coord  upperleft;
    struct coord  lowerright;
} big_box = { { 10, 10 }, { 0, 0 } };
```